# Сделать синонимами метки [файловый-ввод-вывод] и [io]

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, метки, синонимы-меток

Есть две метки:

- [io](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io) (231 вопрос, есть описание)
- [файловый-ввод-вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4) (84 вопроса, нет описания).

Как вы думаете, стоит ли их объединить? Ведь `io` расшифровывается  как `input/output`, и в большинстве вопросов с этой меткой идёт речь о файловом вводе/выводе.

Comment: Ввод-вывод может быть и не файловым. И всё-таки большинство случаев это не все. Путём объединения меток от частного к общему можно в итоге придти к трём меткам "получение-информации", "обработка-информации" и "вывод-информации".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Файловый ввод/вывод - это подмножество ввода/вывода. Не стоит объединять частные метки с более общими.

Например, будет странно, если кто-то задаёт вопрос о *вводе-выводе на экран*, вводит метку [io](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io) (вполне подходящую), и получает на выходе [файловый-ввод-вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4). В обратной же ситуации - будет потерян контекст. Хотел про файлы, а получил обо всём.

Если была бы метка [ввод-вывод](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4), то её безусловно стоило бы синонимизировать с [io](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/io), но такой нет.